# How to see posts with zero votes?

Tags: support, search, filtering

I decided to search for answers (`is:answer`) that have been accepted (`isaccepted:1`) with no votes, so I can go through the list and see if I can upvote both the question and the answer, but...

Is there a filter in the search that returns answers/questions with 0 votes (`votes:0`) **and** those answers/questions match the above criterias?

If I type:

`is:answer isaccepted:1 votes:10`

then it will return posts where an answer has been accepted, but the `votes:10` might not refer to that answer...

Comment: +1 for a noble quest

Comment: Trying hard to earn that `Vox Populi` badge, eh?

Comment: @CodyGray not really. If so, I'd already have it `:)`. 40 votes isn't that much, is it? The thing is that I was thinking about voting up questions, and that idea came up to my mind, but then somebody posted an answer to this question (and then deleted it) talking about the *Unsung Hero* tag. I didn't think about it `:/`

Comment: Hmm, while that's an interesting point, I don't think that should really be a deterrent from upvoting good answers. I'd appreciate the +10 far more than I would the badge... But I don't know of a good way to find these posts, either. Just never spent much time looking.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't mind this will  not return recent posts (max last 7 days) you can use [SEDE](http://data.stackexchange.com).

I have created [this query](https://data.stackexchange.com/meta.stackexchange/query/701859)

```sql
select q.id as [Post Link]
     , 'site://q/' + cast(a.id as nvarchar) +'| Answer ' as [answer link]
from posts q
inner join posts a on q.acceptedanswerid = a.id
where q.score = 0 
and a.score = 0
```

This will return questions that are accepted where both the question and the answer have a score of 0. I wasn't sure if you meant to list accepted question where at least one answer has a score of 0 but that is a bit more difficult (but not impossible) so I leave that for later attempts.

This is the result today:

[image: SEDE result]

Keep in mind SEDE is only updated once a week, on Sunday. If you want to give SEDE a test run yourself, you might find the [awesome tutorial](https://data.stackexchange.com/tutorial) handy.