# Can posts with no votes (as opposed to zero score) be queried?

Tags: support, voting, data-explorer, statistics

I am curious to know how many posts (questions, in particular) have zero score because no one has ever voted on them versus posts with zero score because they have equal (non-zero) numbers of upvotes and downvotes.

Short of going through every post by hand and looking at the total upvotes and downvotes, I can't find a way to query for posts that have no votes of either kind.

I've looked at the search help page, Data Explorer, and the analytics page, and the information I want seems inaccessible.

**Looking for confirmation of the unavailability of this data, or instructions for how to get it.**

Comment: A related problem is sorting posts by the number of votes, up or down.  A post with 10 up-votes and 8 down-votes is going to be far more interesting than a post with a score of 2, but there's no reasonable way of distinguishing between them.

Comment: This question really belongs on the main meta site; it isn't specific to music.

Comment: Here are all questions that have no up or downvotes: https://data.stackexchange.com/music/query/1404568

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Here](https://data.stackexchange.com/music/query/1404470) is an attempt to break down all zero-scoring posts. The query does have a graph but it's not really informative. The first column says 'Votes' but it's actually the number of *up*votes, which equals the number of downvotes. The vast majority are posts which haven't been voted on at all:

[image: table]

Comment: Music seems to be ok, but Stack Overflow has 691 posts where the zero score doesn't match the up/down votes https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1404642/posts-with-votes-inconsistent-with-score. Dangers of denormalization I guess.

Comment: @852172 I guess those are due to a difference in when the `Posts` table was copied and when the `Votes` table was.

Comment: It's *possible* but a lot of those posts are very old, and some of the differences are so large as to make that explanation unlikely, I think.

Comment: I've checked a couple of them and to all old posts happened something around the time of the snapshot: they were voted on, were deleted, etc. I'm pretty sure that explains the difference.

Answer (score 2):

Interesting question, and I found [this discussion](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/91574/how-to-see-posts-with-zero-votes) on Meta that's not exactly the same but similar. The answer (made over six years after the question was asked!) includes a Data Explorer query. You can access a Music version of this query [here](https://data.stackexchange.com/music/query/701859).

I'm not familiar enough with the code (and it's frankly too late for me to think about it now), but it seems one could easily adjust this to focus only on questions as opposed to answers, and in doing so also remove the "accepted" stipulation.

Comment: That code finds zero score posts, but not zero vote posts.

Comment: Oh, I guess so. Bummer...in my late-night doze, the questions I looked at all had +0/-0, but perhaps I just happened to click on the wrong ones.